# Hide if matching dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have dates being outputted on a events list and I want to hide any end dates that match the start date.

For example;

```
<span class="start_date">Wed 23rd January</span>

<span class="end_date">Wed 23rd January</span>
```

I'm trying to add a class to the span around the end date when the date matches the start date, so I can hide it.

Here is the JS I've tried to use so far to see if the two fields match.

```
var a = $('.start_date');
var b = $('.end_date');

if ($.data(a) == $.data(b)) {
    $('.end_date').addClass('hide');
}
```

Comment: What programming language is that? JavaScript?

Comment: Please take a step back, and reread [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), as well as [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML

Answer (score 1):

Just use `text()` instead:

```js
var a = $('.start_date'),
    b = $('.end_date');

if( a.text() == b.text() ) 
{
    $('.end_date').addClass('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="start_date">Wed 23rd January</span>

<span class="end_date">Wed 23rd January</span>
```

Comment: If there is a space in one of the dates (and only in that one), this will not work

Answer (score 0):

Look, no jQuery, :-)

```js
let a = document.querySelector('.start_date');
let b = document.querySelector('.end_date');

if (a.textContent == b.textContent) {
  b.classList.add('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="start_date">Wed 23rd January</span>
<span class="end_date">Wed 23rd January</span>
```

But you may want to trim any leading or trailing whitespace or do other processing to ensure things aren't affected by minor formatting differences (e.g. upper/lower case).